# Conditional math between rows in data table

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, difference

I have the following data table:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(structure(list(var = c("rn_24", "rn_24", "albedo", "albedo", 
"et", "et", "gpp_g", "gpp_g", "ndvi", "ndvi"), land.use = c("lu1", 
"lu2", "lu1", "lu2", "lu1", "lu2", "lu1", "lu2", "lu1", "lu2"
), mean = c(112.785714285714, 115.468333333333, 0.152738095238095, 
0.172816666666667, 97.9797619047619, 93.01, 181.764285714286, 
192.396666666667, 0.769785714285714, 0.584216666666667)), .Names = c("var", 
"land.use", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame"))
```

that looks like this:

```
      var land.use        mean
 1:  rn_24      lu1 112.7857143
 2:  rn_24      lu2 115.4683333
 3: albedo      lu1   0.1527381
 4: albedo      lu2   0.1728167
 5:     et      lu1  97.9797619
 6:     et      lu2  93.0100000
 7:  gpp_g      lu1 181.7642857
 8:  gpp_g      lu2 192.3966667
 9:   ndvi      lu1   0.7697857
10:   ndvi      lu2   0.5842167
```

What I need to do is, for each variable `var`, calculate the relative difference between the `mean` value of land uses lu1 and lu2. For example, for the first variable `rn24` the relative difference would be:

```
( 115.4683333 - 112.7857143 ) / 112.7857143
```

which is equal to `0.0237851`. And so on for all other variables `var`.

Therefore, the expected output would be a new data table that looks like this:

```
      var      rel.diff
 1:  rn_24     0.0237851
 2:  albedo    0.1314577
 3:      et   -0.05072233
 4:   gpp_g    0.05849544
 5:    ndvi   -0.2410658
```

Since my real data table is pretty long, what is the best programatic way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to @g5w's solution, is

```
dt[, .(rel.diff=(mean[land.use == "lu2"] - mean[land.use == "lu1"]) /
                 mean[land.use == "lu1"]), by=var]

      var    rel.diff
1:  rn_24  0.02378510
2: albedo  0.13145752
3:     et -0.05072233
4:  gpp_g  0.05849543
5:   ndvi -0.24106585
```

This is robust to differing ordering in the land.use variable as it uses the values of this variable to index the values of the mean variable.

@Frank's comment mention an algebraic simplification to this solution that reduces the references subsetting:

```
dt[, mean[land.use == "lu2"] / mean[land.use == "lu1"] - 1, by=.(var)]
```

Since (val2 - val1) / val1 = (val2 / val1) - 1.

Comment: This one-liner is amazing! Thanks to @G5W for providing the inspiration for this.

Comment: Alternately, `dt[order(land.use), diff(mean)/mean[2], by=.(var)]` or at least `dt[, mean[land.use=="lu2"]/mean[land.use=="lu1"] - 1, by=.(var)]` to avoid writing the condition twice

Comment: @Frank, I just noticed your first suggested code should be `dt[order(land.use), diff(mean)/mean[1], by=.(var)]` (note the index `1` instead of `2`).

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

`d <- dcast(dt,var~land.use,value.var='mean')`

```
      var         lu1         lu2
1: albedo   0.1527381   0.1728167
2:     et  97.9797619  93.0100000
3:  gpp_g 181.7642857 192.3966667
4:   ndvi   0.7697857   0.5842167
5:  rn_24 112.7857143 115.4683333
```

`data.table(var=d$var,rel.diff=(d$lu2-d$lu1)/d$lu1)`

```
      var    rel.diff
1: albedo  0.13145752
2:     et -0.05072233
3:  gpp_g  0.05849543
4:   ndvi -0.24106585
5:  rn_24  0.02378510
```

Comment: For the second line, folks would typically avoid the `$` like `d[, .(var, rel.diff = lu2/lu1 - 1)]` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

This just needs proper indexing

```
SEQ = seq(2,nrow(dt),2)    
NewDT = data.table(var = dt$var[SEQ], 
    rel.diff = (dt$mean[SEQ] - dt$mean[SEQ-1]) / dt$mean[SEQ-1])
NewDT
     var    rel.diff
1  rn_24  0.02378510
2 albedo  0.13145752
3     et -0.05072233
4  gpp_g  0.05849543
5   ndvi -0.24106585
```